# Breakpoint triggers on device but not simulator

Tags: objective-c, xcode, debugging, breakpoints, ios-simulator

I have a weird situation where Xcode only catches the break point when running on the actual iPhone device, not the simulator.

```
-(IBAction)ping1:(id)sender
{
    // this is the break point
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"dontforgetme" ofType:@"mp3"];
    AVAudioPlayer *sound = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path] error:NULL];
   [sound play];
}
```

Another problem is that when the button is touched, then `ping1` is called and the sound plays, but only for one second or less even though the MP3 file has a 3 minute long sound.

I don't understand any of this. How can it be happening? How can I find the problem?